# Mysterious Manjaro boot issue

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, manjaro, kernel-panic

Since Linux Mint is dropping the KDE desktop, I've been exploring other distros offering KDE to replace it.  I installed Kubuntu, Manjaro, and openSUSE on a USB hard drive to evaluate them side-by-side.  Here's how I set it up:

- I gave each distro a separate partition, they share a swap partition (only one distro is in use at a time), and GRUB in on the USB drive.
- The procedure was to install the first distro (openSUSE), have it install GRUB, get everything updated and configured as close to my ideal as the distro allowed.  Then install the next distro (Manjaro), and finally Kubuntu, each in a similar manner.  Each successive distro replaced GRUB and added all of the previous OSes.  The process got each distro working in a "polished" state, all verified as having no obvious issues.
- Then I started using the distros to evaluate them.  Kubuntu and openSUSE worked fine.  However, Manjaro wouldn't boot.  It gave a screen full of failure data beginning with:

  > Kernel panic - not synching: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0)

  However, it would boot just fine using the "advanced options for Manjaro" selection in GRUB, an option to use a "fallback initramfs".  That's based on the same kernel; the only difference is that it includes what looks like the full set of available drivers rather than the "optimized" minimal set in the default option.  It isn't clear why that should make a difference.

Researching the symptoms, I found a few other reports of similar problems, mainly with Manjaro, Arch (on which Manjaro is based), and a few other distros.  I didn't have any luck with the suggested solutions.

Since it booted fine with the fallback initramfs, I looked for ways to just make that option the main selection for Manjaro.  Didn't get anywhere with that.

Long story short, I went to the Manjaro support forum, and regulars there were familiar with the issue.  I'll post the explanation and solution here as an answer in case anyone else runs into this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the Arch family of distros is very particular about how GRUB is configured.  The Ubuntu family of distros (including Mint), configures GRUB in a way that gives the Arch family indigestion.  Most other popular distros aren't all that particular.  They're happy with the way Ubuntu does it.  They're happy with the way Arch does it.  Ubuntu is happy with the way Arch does it.

So if you are setting up a multi-boot arrangement that includes a distro from the Arch family, like Manjaro, install that last.  That will leave GRUB with a "universally acceptable" configuration.

If you find yourself already in this situation, there is a simple fix that is likely to work (fixed it for me).  That is, let Manjaro update GRUB.

Boot into Manjaro. Open a terminal and enter these commands:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdx
```

where `x` is the identifier for the drive on which you want GRUB installed (like `sda` or `sdb`, for example).

```
sudo update-grub
```

If that doesn't solve it for you, check out the [Manjaro support forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/), which has a lot of discussion and various other solutions.